# How to add job information in jenkins job/project page

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees, hudson-plugins

I want to add scm poll information in project/job page below job name.I checked with project action but didn't find the right action which add information in this Job home page before Permalink. PermalinkProjectAction adds action link in Permalink ,ProminentProjectAction didn't work,Can you specify how to achieve this.

I created an action class of ProminentProjectAction & added in Buildwrapper getProjectAction() along index.jelly but still didn't display.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after workaround.Using **TransientProjectActionFactory**, this will add action to the project irrespective of configuration.I created InvisibleAction put this **Extensionpoint TransientProjectActionFactory** & achieved my goal.